# Animate multiple material transitions

Tags: keyframes

How can I animate an object to have a different material? I made 10 different materials and I want to make a sequence of this object with all (animated) materials.

Comment: Hello, please add more detail about your intended result. For instance : You want your animation to be 250 frames long, and the material to change every 25 frames. Do you want a transition between each material or do you want the change to be total from one frame to the other, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the materials into nodegroups, and switch between them.
This setup can switch between any number of groups by animating the value node.
<sub>(I'm sure this was answered somewhere before, just couldn't find it)</sub>

[image]

[image]